# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "rooms" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just migrated from Sqlite3-local to Postgresql on heroku. One of my view that was working fine now shows  ther following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "rooms" does not exist LINE 8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"rooms"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod, c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation WHERE a.attrelid = '"rooms"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum
```

The controller is simple :

```
def index
@rooms = Room.all
end
```

The console shows the following:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "rooms" does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms" LIMIT $1
                               ^
: SELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms" LIMIT $1
```

The room table is in the database and event contain some dummy data.
Anyone is familiar with this problem please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try Room.all from rails console and see if things are fine?

Comment: Does relation rooms exist in database, did you ran migrations?

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Hey, just added the result of the console. The table is definitely present, it even has some data. When i run `rake db:migrate`, nothing happens, guess nothing too migrate?

Comment: Is your database.yml pointing to right database?
Also check if your table name is "room" or "rooms" as rails pluralize model name while looking for table names

Comment: All other tables are working well. This MVC also used to work well before switching from Sqlite3.

Comment: "The room table is in the database..."  you mean the "rooms" table, right?  Table names by convention are plural in rails (model names are singular)

Comment: the rooms table yes, that is correct. Again it was working perfectly fine before. nothing was changed, except th emigration to Postgresql

Comment: `heroku pg:psql -c '\dt;'` is `rooms` listed in the result?

Comment: Yes i have :
public | rooms | table | ########

Comment: Try to run `spring stop && rails server`

Comment: @Vasilisa, the error is still there after sprint stop and restart.

Comment: I replaced the table locally and it works now, I guess i should do the same in Heroku. Does anyone knows how to drop a table in heroku and replace it  with a new one ?